# understanding "Deep MNIST for Experts"

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am trying to understand [Deep MNIST for Experts](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/tutorials/mnist/pros/index.html#deep-mnist-for-experts). I have a quite clear idea of how Neural networks and deep learning works on a high level, but I struggle to understand the details.

In the tutorial the first write and run a simple one layer model. This includes defining the model x*W+b, calculating the entropy, minimizing the entropy by gradient decent and evaluating the result.

The first part I found quite easy to run and understand.

In the second part the build a simple multi level network, and apply some convolutions and pooling. However, here things start to get tricky. They write:

> We can now implement our first layer. It will consist of convolution, followed by max pooling. The convolutional will compute 32 features for each 5x5 patch.

A 5x5 patch should equal 25 pixels. Right? Why would you extract 32 features from 25 pixels? Why do you want more features than you have datapoints? How does this even make sense? It feels like they are "upscaling" a problems from 25 dimensions to 32 dimensions. It feels like that 7 of the 32 dimensions should be redudant.

Secondly. The convolution uses the function [truncated_normal](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/constant_op.html#truncated_normal) which just picks random values close to the mean. Why is this a good model for modelling handwritten numbers?

Thirdly. The second layer in the network seems to do the same thing again. Are more layers just better, could I have achieved the same results with a single layer?

Comment: The tutorial assumes knowledge of convolutional networks. I think it would ease your exploration to read on the CN model first. There you'll find that features are characteristics found in the image. Each feature works on the complete image (feature maps), so it is not really up scaling. It is rather "looking" at the image in different ways. Note that I have doubts this is an SO question, so I do not post a fully-fledged answer. Perhaps a forum or resources like Nielsen's book can help.

Comment: This would also be a more appropriate question for the Data Science SE, or possibly CV. Also, one question per question is highly preferable to a 3-in-1 question for all parties involved. It will help future readers find the post they need more easily, it keeps from overwhelming people who want to help you, and it gets you more answers because it avoids precluding people who have answers to 1 or 2 of your 3 questions from answering.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Data Science SE

Answer (score 4):

I think a visual model can greatly reduce the difficulty of understanding, so perhaps this can help you understand better:

http://scs.ryerson.ca/~aharley/vis/conv/

This is a 3D visualization of a convolutional neural network, it has two convolution layers and followed with two max pooling layers, you can click a 3D cube in each layer to check the value.

Answer (score 2):

So in general you have to read a lot about CNNs/NN before trying to understand what is really going on. These examples are not really supposed to be introduction course to NN, these do assume you know what CNNs are.

> A 5x5 patch should equal 25 pixels. Right? Why would you extract 32 features from 25 pixels? Why do you want more features than you have datapoints? How does this even make sense? It feels like they are "upscaling" a problems from 25 dimensions to 32 dimensions. It feels like that 7 of the 32 dimensions should be redudant.

This is completely different 'level of abstraction', you are comparing unrelated objects to each other, which is obviously confusing. They are creating 32 **filters**, each will linearly map your whole image, through a 5x5 convolution kernel moving through your image. For example one such filter could be an edge detector:

```
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
```

another can detect diagonal lines

```
1 0 0 0 0
1 1 0 0 0
1 1 1 0 0
1 1 1 1 0
1 1 1 1 1
```

etc. Why 32? Just a magical number, tested empirically. This is actually quite small number in terms of CNNs (notice that just to detect basic edges in greyscale images you already need 8 different filters!).

> Secondly. The convolution uses the function truncated_normal which just picks random values close to the mean. Why is this a good model for modelling handwritten numbers?

This is **initializer of the weights**. This is not a "model for modelling handrwitten numbers", this is simply a starting point for optimization of this part of the parameters space. Why normal distribution? We have some mathematical intuition how to initalize neural nets, especially assuming ReLU activations. It is important to initialize in a random way, which ensures that many of your neurons will be initially active, so you do not get 0 derivatives (thus lack of ability to learn using typical optimizers).

> Thirdly. The second layer in the network seems to do the same thing again. Are more layers just better, could I have achieved the same results with a single layer?

In principle you can model everything with a single-hidden layer feed forward net, even without convolutions. However, it might require **exponentialy as many** hidden units, and perfect optimization strategies which **we do not have** (and maybe they do not even exist!). Depth of the network gives you ability to express more complex (and for same cases more useful) features with less parameters, plus we know more or less how to optimize it. However you should avoid an often pitfall of assuming "deeper is better". This is not true in general. This is true **if important features of your data can be efficiently expressed as a hierarchical structure of abstraction**. It is true for images (more and more complex patterns, first edges, then some lines and curves, then patches, then more complex concepct etc.) as well as text, sound etc. but before you try to apply DL for your new task you should ask yourself whether this is (or at least might be) true for your case. Using too complex model is usually way worse than too simple.